# Evaluate triangle by its side

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators, prompt

My question is about using Javascript to do triangle evaluation by its sides. The following code is very initial version even it works. I'd like to know whether it could be more simplifying or there is other way to achieve the same result.

Thanks!

```
let a = Number(prompt('Please input the the first side (a)'))
let b = Number(prompt('Please input the the second side (b)'))
let c = Number(prompt('Please input the the third side (c)'))

if (a + b <= c || b + c <= a || c + a <= b || Number.isNaN(a) || Number.isNaN(b) || Number.isNaN(c) || a == "" || b == "" || c == ""){
  console.log("invalid")
}
else if ((a > 0 && b >0 && c >0 ) && (a == b && b == c && c == a)){
  console.log("equilateral triangle")
}
else if ((a > 0 && b >0 && c >0 ) && (a == b || b == c || c == a)){
  console.log("isosceles triangle")
}
else {
  console.log("scalene triangle")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way could be to explicitly convert the lengths to a number (0 for NaN) and sort them first. And a ternary operator can be useful here also:

```
let [d, e, f] = [a, b, c].map(a => +a || 0).sort((a, b) => a-b);
let result = d + e <= f     ? "invalid"
           : d === f        ? "equilateral"
           : d < e && e < f ? "scalene"
                            : "isosceles";
console.log(result);
```

This will not be the fastest when doing many thousands of them, but I like the look of it.

#### Explanation

`[a, b, c]` turns the three values into an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

[`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a method available for arrays. For each original value in `[a, b, c]` the following (arrow) function is executed,

```
a => +a || 0
```

`map` creates a new array consisting of the results of calling that function on each separate value (so first with `a`, then with `b` and finally with `c`)

`+a` uses the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) as a short way of turning a value into a number, which means that you could omit the `Number()` calls you did in the first three lines of your code. When the result of this is `NaN` or 0, then `|| 0` will kick in: instead of `NaN` or 0, 0 will be taken instead ([`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) is a logical OR operator and 0 will only be used when the left side is considered "falsy"). This practically means that `NaN` is replaced by 0.

So up to now the code has roughly done something similar to the following:

```
let newarray = [];
newarray[0] = +a;
if (Number.isNaN(newarray[0])) newarray[0] = 0;
newarray[1] = +b;
if (Number.isNaN(newarray[1])) newarray[1] = 0;
newarray[2] = +c;
if (Number.isNaN(newarray[2])) newarray[2] = 0;
```

Then another array method is called on that array returned by `.map()`: the method [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). That method will use the provided callback function `(a, b) => a-b` to make comparisons in the array and sort it based on the values returned by such calls. It is up to the `sort` method to decide for which pairs this function is called. When the returned value is negative, it means the compared values are already in increasing order. When positive, they should be rearranged. When zero, they should be considered equal to the sort algorithm.

So... we now have an array that consists of numbers which are guaranteed to no longer have a `NaN`, and which are sorted in ascending order.

Then that array is *assigned* using so-called [*destructuring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
let [d, e, f] =
```

This means that the individual values of the sorted array are assigned one by one to three new variables. So this is roughly short for:

```
let d = new_sorted_array[0];
let e = new_sorted_array[1];
let f = new_sorted_array[2];
```

Because these values are now ordered, we can use them for much simpler comparisons to decide on the shape of the triangle. What follows is an expression using a chain of [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which much resemble an `if (...) ... else if ...` chain. So:

```
let result = d + e <= f     ? "invalid"
           : d === f        ? "equilateral"
           : d < e && e < f ? "scalene"
                            : "isosceles";
```

... is short for this:

```
let result;
if (d + e <= f) result ="invalid"
else if (d === f) result = "equilateral"
else if (d < e && e < f) result = "scalene"
else result = "isosceles";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If possible, could you please explain more detail about your solution? Especially ".map(a => +a || 0).sort((a, b) => a-b);"  I am curious about this part.

Comment: Added explanations.

Comment: very clear explanation. Truly appreciated! There is another question about this part: ": d === f        ? "equilateral" Don't we need to code d===f && e===f?

Comment: Aha, good question! That's where the benefit of the sorting comes into play. If you know that d <= e <= f (because of the sorting), then it is enough to know that d === f, because it immediately implies that also d === e and e === f.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce alot of bulk and change the implementation:

1. You can make the user input a function call
2. You can place the input into an array
3. You can use `every` to make sure every value is greater than 0
4. You can use a new Set to remove duplicates, if the size is 1, then all sides are the same, if it's 2, then 2 sides are the same, if it's 3, all sides are different

```js
const getSide = l => Number(prompt(`Please input the the second side (${l})`))
const sides = [getSide('a'), getSide('b'), getSide('c')]

if (sides.every(el => el > 0)) {
  const size = new Set(sides).size
  if (size === 1) console.log("equilateral triangle")
  else if (size === 2) console.log("isosceles triangle")
  else console.log("scalene triangle")
} else {
  console.log("invalid")
}
```

Test cases:

```js
const test = sides => {
  if (sides.every(el => el > 0)) {
    const size = new Set(sides).size
    if (size === 1) console.log("equilateral triangle")
    else if (size === 2) console.log("isosceles triangle")
    else console.log("scalene triangle")
  } else {
    console.log("invalid")
  }
}

test([0,1,2]) // invalid
test([NaN,NaN,NaN]) // invalid
test(['',1,2]) // invalid
test([3,3,3]) // eq
test([2,2,3]) // iso
test([1,2,3]) // sca
```

Comment: [1, 1, 3] should give "invalid".

Comment: @trincot I see, all I've done is simplify OP's code, not added anymore implementation :)